# Exporting TFS 2010 Build Definitions

Tags: tfs

I built a 'proof of concept' TFS 2010 build server. Now I want to set the build server up else where and move my old build definitions to the new build server. For the life of me I cannot figure out where the file location for the build definitions are? Is there a way to export this data out of my old build server and into my new? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Are you moving the Project Collection(s) to a new server or did you just set up a new server to be used as a build agent?

If it's the former, you don't need to worry about exporting the build definitions because they will move with everything else in the collection

[Move a Team Project Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936138.aspx)

If it's the latter, you also don't need to export anything. You'll either update the build controller to include the new build agent you set up, or you'll update the build definition to use a new build controller (depending what new components you are adding to TFS)

The build definitions are in the project collection database and you really shouldn't need to access them directly.

Comment: The key to Mike's comments are likely that you need to add that server as an agent of your Build Controller.

Answer (score 0):

The build definitions are on the TFS Data Tier (SQL Server) that your team project collection is on. You don't need to move them to a new build server. Any build machine associated with that team project collection can run your build definition.